# Convergence to zero in measure and bounded $L^1$ norm implies convergence of $\sqrt{f*g}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Let $\{f_n\}$ $\subset$ $L^1(E)$.

Show that if $f_n$ $\rightarrow$ $0$ in measure and $\sup||f_n||_1 < \infty$ then for every $g \in L^1(E)$:

$\int_E \sqrt{f_n(x) \cdot g(x)} dx \rightarrow 0$

I tried to tackle the question as follows:

Let $g \in L^1(E)$, then we can set C = $\int_E |g(x)|dx < \infty$.

Now, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we get:

$|\int_E \sqrt{|f_n(x) \cdot g(x)|}dx\ |^2 \leqslant \Bigl( \int_E \bigr (\sqrt{|f_n(x)|}\ \bigr)^2 \Bigl) \cdot \Bigl( \int_E \bigr (\sqrt{|g(x)|}\ \bigr)^2 \Bigl) = $

$=\Bigl( \int_E|f_n(x)|dx \Bigl) \cdot \Bigl( \int_E|g(x)|dx \Bigl)=C \cdot \Bigl( \int_E|f_n(x)|dx \Bigl)$

It is given that $\{f_n\} \rightarrow 0$ in measure and  $\sup||f_n||_1 < \infty$.
So from what I understand, if I can show that (*) for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a measurable set $A$ with $\mu(A)<\infty$ such that $\bigl| \int_\text{E\A} f_n\bigl|<\epsilon$, then by Vitali's theorem, $\{f_n\}$ converges in $L_1$ to $0$. That is, $||f_n||_1 \rightarrow 0$

$\implies |\int_E \sqrt{|f_n(x) \cdot g(x)|}dx\ |^2 \leqslant C \cdot \Bigl( \int_E|f_n(x)|dx \Bigl) = C\cdot||f_n||_1 \rightarrow 0.$

As requested.

I'm having trouble showing (*), can anyone help me with this question?
Maybe there is a different direction?
I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot show it, because it's not true in general. However it would be true if you had a sequence of functions which are bounded in $L^2$ and are converging to 0 in measure; so my advice is not to use this technique on $f_n$ but on $\sqrt f_n$ instead (for example, start from the case $g$ uniformly bounded)

Comment: and why do you think the square roots are defined?

Comment: zhw that was a question I came across, so I guess it is given that the square roots are defined as well, so f_n and g are integrable so in real analysis course we’ve learned that f_n *g integrable as well, there for you can bound the integral of sqrt(f*g) with the integral of |f*g| which is finite and there for sqrt(f*g) is integrable. Thank you Lucio and zhw.